# Eclipse update fails with "There were no installable units selected when the plan was computed."

Tags: eclipse

I had Eclipse installed on my old laptop.  I was getting a new laptop, and I copied the eclipse tree and my workspace to the new laptop.  Most everything appears to work on the new laptop, but I noticed today when I saw a plugin update come through.  I tried updating on both the old and new laptops.  The update on the old laptop went through fine, but the update attempt on the new laptop fails with "There were no installable units selected when the plan was computed."

This is the log file excerpt corresponding to the attempt:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 0 2012-02-03 16:34:51.791
>   !MESSAGE Operation details !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
>   4 1 2012-02-03 16:34:51.791 !MESSAGE Cannot complete the install
>   because one or more required items could not be found. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2012-02-03 16:34:51.791 !MESSAGE
>   Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1328029049876
>   (SharedProfile_com.springsource.sts.ide 1.0.0.1328029049876) !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2012-02-03 16:34:51.791 !MESSAGE
>   Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1328029049876
>   (SharedProfile_com.springsource.sts.ide 1.0.0.1328029049876) requires
>   'org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.1.0.20120130-2016]' but it could not be
>   found
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 0 2012-02-03 16:34:52.325
>   !MESSAGE Operation details !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
>   4 1 2012-02-03 16:34:52.325 !MESSAGE Cannot complete the install
>   because one or more required items could not be found. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2012-02-03 16:34:52.325 !MESSAGE
>   Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1328029049876
>   (SharedProfile_com.springsource.sts.ide 1.0.0.1328029049876) !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2012-02-03 16:34:52.325 !MESSAGE
>   Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1328029049876
>   (SharedProfile_com.springsource.sts.ide 1.0.0.1328029049876) requires
>   'org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.1.0.20120130-2016]' but it could not be
>   found
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 0 2012-02-03 16:34:52.362
>   !MESSAGE Operation details !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
>   4 1 2012-02-03 16:34:52.362 !MESSAGE Cannot complete the install
>   because one or more required items could not be found. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2012-02-03 16:34:52.362 !MESSAGE
>   Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1328029049876
>   (SharedProfile_com.springsource.sts.ide 1.0.0.1328029049876) !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2012-02-03 16:34:52.362 !MESSAGE
>   Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1328029049876
>   (SharedProfile_com.springsource.sts.ide 1.0.0.1328029049876) requires
>   'org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.1.0.20120130-2016]' but it could not be
>   found
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui 4 0 2012-02-03 16:34:52.438 !MESSAGE
>   There were no installable units selected when the plan was computed.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui 4 0 2012-02-03 16:34:52.440 !MESSAGE
>   There were no installable units selected when the plan was computed.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui 4 0 2012-02-03 16:34:52.440 !MESSAGE
>   There were no installable units selected when the plan was computed.

Comment: Looks like your missing some maven dependencies. What OS are you running?

Comment: Win7.  I copied the .m2 tree from the old XP laptop, and it's well populated.  Is there some reason a copied .m2 tree wouldn't be valid?

Comment: I tried moving my repository directory out of the way so it could regenerate its repository.  I was able to build my project from the command line, but after I finally got back into Eclipse and tried to update again, I got the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved this.  This was a "Windows Seven/Program Files" issue.  You can't install STS or Eclipse into "Program Files" because it needs to write into the application directory, and it's not normally run with admin rights.

I wish this didn't result in such an obtuse symptom.  You'd think it would have at least reported something like "couldn't write to application directory".

Comment: Thanks for sharing this and saving me a lot of time with the same issue! It definitely would be helpful if Eclipse gave a clearer error message.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, and solved this by running eclipse.exe "as administrator" to perform the update:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was that I had (on Mac OSX) previously installed the plugin I was trying to update as superuser.  The solution was to launch eclipse as superuser.

```
$ sudo /Applications/development/eclipse/eclipse
```

(there is a handy link to eclipse at the root of your eclipse folder).